# Order of CSS properties

Tags: css, web-applications

I think it would be convenient to write CSS rule properties always in the same order. Is there any convention of this ordering ?

I noticed `Firebug` displays CSS properties in an alphabetical order. Why ? Does not HTTP preserve the original order of CSS rules?

Answer (score 5):

Negative.  It is a good practice to keep like-properties together but past that there is no "order-of-operations" like there is for selectors.

However, the last rule of a type WILL be taken over the previous one.

Example:

```
background-color: #000;
background: #FFF url(image.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat;
```

The color (should the image fail to load) will be `white` now because it came last.

Example #2:

```
border: none;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
```

Will result in all borders being empty but then giving the right edge a border of `1px solid #000` by over-riding the first declaration.

**EDIT:**  This first-is-the-worst logic is also applied when assigning properties across different selectors throughout the document.

### This:

```
body * {
    margin: 0;
}
...further down
#main {
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

allows `#main` to give itself a `margin` because it came after.  Of course, the selector specificity would allow this to happen even if `#main` was given *before* `body *`, but you get the idea.  You can read up on why that's true **[right here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)**

Comment: Could you give an example of "like-properties" ?

Comment: @Michael: Like properties might include all the `background-` rules, for example. `background-attachment`, `background-image` - you'd group these. Another example could be fonts: `font-family`, `color`, `font-size`.

Comment: E.g. `border-radius` and `border`.

Comment: Actually border-radius and border are independent of each other.  You can have a border of 0 and still keep a radius oddly enough :)

Comment: Thanks. BTW do you know about any "beautifier" for CSS to group like-properties together and make the CSS properties ordered in the same order across all CSS files?

Comment: haha actually yeah it's literally called "CSS Code Beautifier" http://www.codebeautifier.com/  I've tried it but I never end up using it cuz I keep editing my stuff lol